# Unable to return anything from node.js rest service

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I know this is a failing in my knowledge but I can not work it out. I've spent the last couple of hours browsing and trying variations but I can not work out what is wrong.

I have written a success piece of node.js that when run from the command line returns a table, in JSON form, from a local AWS DynamoDB.

I am now trying to turn that into a lamda call. And there's where it goes wrong. I can not get the lamda to return anything and I don't know why. I'm pretty sure it's because I don't understand how the callback mechanism works but reading around that hasn't help and hasn't allowed me to stumble over the answer.

This is the code I've got:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

let id =  (event.pathParameters || {}).division || false;
switch(event.httpMethod){

    case "GET":

        if(id) {
            //callback(null, {body: "Returning Divison " + id});

            AWS.config.update({
                region: "us-west-2",
                endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
              });

            var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
            var table = 'League';

            var params = {
                TableName : table,
                KeyConditionExpression: "#division = :division",
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#division": "division"
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":division": id
                }
            };

            docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err)
                {
                    //console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                    callback(err, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    //console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                    callback(null, JSON.stringify(data.Item));
                }
            })

            break;
        }                

        callback(null, {body: "Return all divisions"});
        break;

    default:
        // Send HTTP 501: Not Implemented
        console.log("Error: unsupported HTTP method (" + event.httpMethod + ")");
        callback(null, { statusCode: 501 })

}
```

}

If I comment out the `docClient.query` call it works and returns stuff to the browser (just the one line messages though). When I include it fails and I get the following message from SAM:

```
Function 'TableGetTest' timed out after 3 seconds
Function returned an invalid response (must include one of: body, headers or statusCode in the response object). Response received: b''
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a connection error. It would appear that the instance of SAM-Local cannot connect to the local instance of dynamoDB.

I'm now looking at how I get SAM-Local access to the local machine (it can't seem to see outside of its container).